# how to keep the scrollbar at the bottom visual basic

Tags: vba, scroll

In my a form, I have a rich text box with vertical scrollbars. I have set it so that a line is read from a local text file, and added to the existing text in the text box. The following code makes it so that a line is read from the text file, there is 3 seconds of pause, and then another line is read and added to the existing text. This is done the emulate the feeling of a messenger application, so the 3 seconds of pause is absolutely necessary.

However, I have found that whenever a new line is added and there is enough text in the rich text box for the scrollbar to appear, the scrollbar will jump to the top. Every new line is added to the bottom, so this is extremely annoying, because it means the user is sent all the way up to the top of the text every single time there is a new line added.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? i.e: locking the scrollbar to the bottom?  Or having the scrollbar automatically scroll down to the bottom whenever there is a new line added?

If you need any pictures or further code, please let me know.

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Call Pause(3)
    RichTextBox1.Text = R.ReadLine()
    Do Until i = lineCount
        Call Pause(3)
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + R.ReadLine()
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

The pause subroutine:

```
Public Sub Pause(ByVal seconds As Single)
    Dim newDate As Date
    newDate = DateAndTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds)
    While DateAndTime.Now.Second <> newDate.Second
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `richTextBox1.AppendText()` instead of "+" (or "&" as it should be) and then  `richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()`.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! AppendText worked without the need for ScrollToCaret. However, there is an issue with the scrollbar in that if I hold it down as the next line is being appended, the process stops and doesn't resume, meaning no more lines are read. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are not the same. Which is it? Please remove the appropriate tag. Also, _**if**_ this is VB.NET then you ought to remove all the `Call` keywords as well. They're not needed as you can call the method without it: `Pause(3)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent apologies I think I wrote down VB and it automatically changed it to VB.NET

Comment: It shouldn't. If you hold the scrollbar thumb down, this will block the update of the RichTextBox. It will resume as soon as you release the thumb. But I don't know what your `Pause()` method is and how it's working. If it's using `Thread.Sleep()`, it should get back to work when you release the thumb. Btw, `ScrollToCaret()` is needed.

Comment: @Jimi What will ScrollToCaret() be necessary for? The code seems to be working fine without it. Also, the pause() is using a loop because Thread.Sleep() froze the entire application. As so. I've updated it into the post so that it's easier to see.
    Public Sub Pause(ByVal seconds As Single)
        Dim newDate As Date
        newDate = DateAndTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds)
        While DateAndTime.Now.Second <> newDate.Second
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub

Comment: Your loop in the `Pause()` method is causing the the event you describe. Place this inside the `Do Loop` of the file reader: `For x As Integer = 1 To 30  Thread.Sleep(10) Application.DoEvents() Next`. You'll see that the updating process is resumed when you block it dragging the Form of holding down the thumb. You'll need a class variable that informs the loop that it's time to break if the Form is closing. About `ScrollToCaret()`: appending text to the RTB does not cause it to scroll. If it does, there's something else responsible for it.

Answer (score -1):

After the TextChangedEvent you can try to set the caret to the last postiton and then use [ScrollToCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_ScrollToCaret)

Comment: But I'm not sure if it is even necessary to seek the caret to the end or if the caret is already on the end after you append new text.